# How to find the position of the n-th occurrance of an element

Tags: excel

In excel I have two columns, say the following:

```
A        B
apple    fruit
beef     meat
banana   fruit
orange   fruit
bacon    meat
```

I then want to access all the elements of column A which correspond to an element B, i.e. I have a column C which should contain the following elements:

```
C
apple
banana
orange
```

i.e. the first element in column C is the first element in column A, for which the element in column B is "fruit".
The second element in column C is the *second* slement in column A, for which the element in column B is "fruit".

I have looked at some formulas, but none of them seem to be able to solve this problem.

I was expecting to at least find the n-th occurrance of some element in column B with a formula like

```
=find("fruit";b1:b5;1)
```

for the first element and

```
=find("fruit";b1:b5;2)
```

for the second element. But `find` is already used in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

Building it stepwise in simpler formulas, I did the following:

```
  D1="fruit"
  D2=IF($D$1=B2,1,0)
  E1=0
  E2=D2+E1
  F2=1
  F3=2
  F4=3
  ... etc.

  G2=MATCH(F2,E:E,0)-1
  H2=OFFSET($A$1,G2,0,1,1)
```

D col is used to id the B col you entered in D1.
E col is used to build a list of "1st, 2nd, ..etc" items related.
F col is just a fixed number list - this are the items we want from E, compressed.
G col is MATCH of F on E. Ie What actual Row number is it on.
H col uses OFFSET to pull the value.

Comment: FYI one could definitely combine some of those formulas to use less columns if desired - I kept them separated for ease of understanding ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this array formula in `C1`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$5,SMALL(IF(B$1:B$5="Fruit",ROW(A$1:A$5)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down - when qualifying values run out you get blanks

Comment: Very nice, I had thought of going down the array formula route, but started confusing myself with it!

Comment: This is slick,  however, it seems to only pull the first item?  How does it pull the "n-th" item? ie the 2nd item: banana, or 3rd item: orange? (I read OP as needing the n-th item ;) )

Comment: The formula in C1 gets the first item. When you copy down the ROWS function increments from 1 to 2 to 3 etc. In the formula ROWS function gives you the k value in the SMALL function hence getting each successive row number where the condition matches

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want...

In range A1:B5 I copied your table

In cell, E1 I typed

```
fruit
```

(This is what you'll be using to determine the list of items you want)
then, in cell F1, I entered

```
=MATCH($E$1,$B$1:$B$5,0)
```

This gets the position in the list of FIRST instance of fruit.
Then, in cell F2, I entered

```
=MATCH($E$1,OFFSET($B$1:$B$5,F1,0),0)+F1
```

This gets the position in the list of FIRST instance of fruit in the OFFSET list and adds the position of the first item to get the position of the second and so on. This formula can then be copied down as far as it needs to go. Then in G1, I entered

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,F1)
```

This can also be filled down as far as it needs to go